# Snmp graphs showing high traffic on switch but not in machine interface

Tags: ubuntu, switch, snmp, cacti

I've setup a **SNMP server** on the office with ubuntu and cacti. It's connected to a 22 port **switch**. I've configured the following SNMP devices: 2 adsl routers, 1 peplink balancer, 1 wifi access point, 2 SMC switches and the SNMP server itself. The polling interval is 1 minute.

This is the graph for the switch port connected to the SNMP server:

[image: swith port connected to snmp server]

And this is the graph for the server interface connected to switch:

[image: server interface connected to the switch]

Who is lying?

Comment: The first graphic shows not traffic at all for outbound. Are you sure you have cacti configured correctly for this switch?

Comment: @SvW dammit I completely ignored that! I used the default options for everything, but it seems I'll have to setup something more specific for the switches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALWAYS TRY TO UPDATE YOUR FIRMWARE!!

So embarrassed of this :$ It cost me 6 mails to SMC support, but finally they send me the latest firmware for our switch models and now everything is working as it should be:

[image: switch graph]

[image: server graph]